# Datetime won't convert from string

Tags: python, datetime, valueerror

```
x = '2022-08-01 12:15:36'
y = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-&d %H:%M:%S')
print(y)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: time data '2022-08-01 12:15:36' does not match format '%Y-%m-&d %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

I am pretty sure the format I have got is okay? I want to be able to find times within a window of this time but can't add time to a string so I need it in date time format.

Comment: The code and error do not match. Error says you have `.%f` in there as well - and, well, there's no dot in your string, so it fails.

Comment: Btw your error doesn't match your code because it tells you that the format '%Y-%m-&d %H:%M:%S.%f' so check in your code if you have some other references, and in documentation i don't find nothing about %f

Comment: the .%f I added at a later point as a Hail Mary which didn't work out but I didn't update the code on here. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the format on "&d".. it should be this one

```
y = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Just turns out I have fat fingers then!